# Apply changes to every Scene

Tags: java, android, android-transitions

I just want to know if there is any method to connect for example TextView's that they will show the same text in every Scene.

I hope you can help me because that would safe much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a class that holds all your strings, statically that you would like to use throughout your scenes.
Implement the appropriate getters and setters for these Strings.
Eg. Example class name `AllStringsText`.

`public static String string1 = "Please press here...";`

In your individual classes create fields that hold the same values as the strings in `AllStringsText`.

`String string1 = AllStringsText.string1;`

Check whether the String has changed by comparing the field in the individual scenes to the string in `AllStrings`.

```
if(!string1.equals(AllStrings.string1)){
     // String in the AllStrings class has changed.
}
```

If it has changed set the `TextView` equal to the new string in the `AllStrings` and update the reference to it in the individual class you are in.

`textView.setText(string1)`

This is not the best way of doing it but I think it is a simple, hacky way to implement this functionality. Note: you *must* check for a change in all individual classes to make sure the changes are made throughout your app.

I hope this helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below.

Comment: First thank you. So out of your answer I conclude that there is no implementation by the Android SDK. Thought your answer helps a lot i will use this solution in future.

Comment: Thank you. I am glad that my answer is a solution that you will use in the future. If my answer answered your question please accept!